# SQL query summarize items per employee - date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure with possibility to filter date ranges.
And I want to be shown grouped, without dates my data. In some period how was SUM all prospects visits per employee.

Now I have this but it isn't good enough. I should remove av.Date, but without av.Date, I cant filter my date range!

```
Select emp.Name+' '+emp.Surname as TaskOwner,av.Date,et.Event,COUNT(av.EventTypeID) as something
from TableT av
left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD
left join EventType et on av.EventTypeID = et.EventTypeID
Group By av.Date, et.Event, emp.Name+' '+emp.Surname
Order By TaskOwner desc
```

My current output is like

```
John Doe    2016-03-02  PROPOSALS ACCEPTED  1
John Doe    2016-03-04  PROSPECTS VISITS    2
John Doe    2016-03-07  COMMERCIAL VISITS   1
John Doe    2016-03-08  PROPOSALS MADE          1
John Doe    2016-03-13  PROPOSALS ACCEPTED  1
Someone Else    2016-01-04  PROPOSALS MADE          1
Someone Else    2016-03-03  COMMERCIAL VISITS   1
Someone Else    2016-03-04  PROPOSALS ACCEPTED  1
Someone Else    2016-03-06  PROPOSALS ACCEPTED  1
```

What I need is something like this:

```
John Doe        PROPOSALS ACCEPTED  2
John Doe        PROSPECTS VISITS    2
John Doe        COMMERCIAL VISITS   1
John Doe        PROPOSALS MADE      1
Someone Else    PROPOSALS MADE      1
Someone Else    COMMERCIAL VISITS   1
Someone Else    PROPOSALS ACCEPTED  2
```

But do be able to filter through date ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below query

```
Select 
  emp.Name+' '+emp.Surname as TaskOwner,
  et.Event,
  COUNT(av.EventTypeID) as something
from TableT av
  left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD
  left join EventType et on av.EventTypeID = et.EventTypeID
Where 
  (ISNULL (@lowerdate) OR av.Date >= ISNULL(CAST(@lowerdate as datetime))
  AND 
  (ISNULL (@higherdate ) OR av.Date <= CAST(@higherdate as datetime) )
 -- this is how we filter, assuming you get two dates always and also taking care of NULL
Group By et.Event, emp.Name+' '+emp.Surname
Order By TaskOwner desc
```